# Enviar pdf por medio de función mail

Tags: php

espero me puedan ayudar, trato de adjuntar un pdf generado con la libreria `dompdf`,quiero  usar la función mail de php para enviar el pdf, pero no me deja me marca este error:

> Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

el código que genera el pdf esta bien, ya genero el pdf sin problemas, pero no logro enviarlo, se que hay una librería `PHPMailer`, pero por ahora quiero usar esta función `mail` de php para mandar el pdf este es el código que estoy implementando para tratar de enviar el pdf:

```
 <?php require_once ("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");


 $dompdf= new DOMPDF();
   $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
     $dompdf->render();
     $pdf=$dompdf->output();
     $filename= $f['cod_cotizacion'].'-'.$f['nombreEmpresa'].'.pdf';

     $dompdf->stream($filename,array("Attachment"=> 0));
     $dompdf->setPaper('A4','landscape');


     $body="Hola buena tarde";
      $mm = new Mail_mime("\n");
     $mm->setTxtBody($body);
     $mm->addAttachment($pdf,'application/pdf','output.pdf', false);

     $body = $mm->get();
     $headers = $mm->headers(array('From'=>$from,'Subject'=>$subject));

     $mail =& Mail::factory('gabox-@hotmail.com');
     if($mail->send($to,$headers,$body)){
         echo "Se envio";
     }


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefiero usar `PHPMailer`, pero prueba con este código...

**Fuente:** [www.codexworld.com](https://www.codexworld.com/send-email-with-attachment-php/)

```
<?php
//recipient
$to = 'recipient@example.com';

//sender
$from = 'sender@example.com';
$fromName = 'CodexWorld';

//email subject
$subject = 'PHP Email with Attachment by CodexWorld'; 

//attachment file path
$file = "codexworld.pdf";

//email body content
$htmlContent = '<h1>PHP Email with Attachment by CodexWorld</h1>
    <p>This email has sent from PHP script with attachment.</p>';

//header for sender info
$headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

//boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

//headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

//multipart boundary 
$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 

//preparing attachment
if(!empty($file) > 0){
    if(is_file($file)){
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb");
        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file));

        @fclose($fp);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" . 
        "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\";     size=".filesize($file).";\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    }
}
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
$returnpath = "-f" . $from;

//send email
$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath); 

//email sending status
echo $mail?"<h1>Mail sent.</h1>":"<h1>Mail sending failed.</h1>";
```